# How do I start a redis server with its own config from Python?

Tags: python, database, redis

I want to use redis as a database for my Python application, kind of like how sqlite is used. I do have a redis server running on my Ubuntu server, but I want Python to use its own server, configured to snapshot the database in a specific path. I know I can fire up a second redis server on another port manually, but I wish to launch the redis server and configure it from Python.

PS: How expensive is running a redis server, as opposed to just reusing the system-wide server?